# Potential CSS Scroll Snap bug in Chrome (Windows). Two examples, only one work. Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll-snap

I found two CSS scroll-snaps examples from [csstricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/). However,  one of them does not work on Chrome on Windows.

- [Example #0](https://codepen.io/jontin/pen/BaaYqWp) - works
- [Example #3](https://codepen.io/jontin/pen/QWWQZpq) - does not work

What is the difference between the two examples? Why does one of them work, and not the other?

Example 1:

```css
.container {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    &.proximity {
            scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
    }
}

li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: 3rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: rgba(white, .5);
    background: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Example 2:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Edit: Thanks to Kaiido for solving this issue. As a I suspected it also solved the problem I had on a project I have been working on. I have sent an email to csstricks.com to notify them about the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by default the `<body>` doesn't scroll, `<html>` does.
 Change the selector to `:root` and it will work in Chrome.

Though to be safe you'd be better defining your own scrolling area since older browsers were indeed using `<body>` as `scrollingElement`.

Comment: Thanks. I have sent an email to csstricks.com to let them know. As suspected, it also solved a problem I had on  one of my own [web projects](https://jontingvold.github.io/responsive-multicolumn-layout/). But the web page was to complex to let others debug. Again, thanks a lot.